# Linear combination and Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1. Consider a set of five arbitrary 2x2 matrices. Can you always write one as a linear combination of the others? Explain. Repeat for five arbitrary 3x3 matrices.
2. For each of the following sets explain whether or not the set is/could be a basis for the space mentioned.
   a) Four vectors in   that form a loop when end-to-end connected. 
   ...............
   Problem is i didnt understand the questions.
   **For the first question**: 
    i know what linear combination is, but Do i have to find that five matrices? which can be linear combination of one another ? or is asking that whether any 5 matrices can be linear combination of one another or cant? 
   **For the second question:** 
   i have learned Standard basis of matrix, (actually learning) but there is no **standard**. Im just started learning and bit confused 
   if any1 explain it little bit i will figure it out.
   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the first question is asking whether every set of five $2\times 2$ contains one that is a linear combination of the other four; the second part is asking the same question about sets of five $3\times 3$ matrices. The first part can be paraphrased as follows: is every set of five $2\times 2$ matrices linearly dependent? Similarly for the second part of the first question.

The second question is asking whether four geometric vectors that form a loop can be a basis. An example of such a loop in $\Bbb R^2$ is shown here:

[image]

HINT: What’s the sum of four vectors that form a loop?

Comment: set of five means: 5 different matrices right ? not every elements  are 5. <br>

Comment: @user3078437: Yes, a set of five matrices. They might not be different matrices, but there are five of them, and they can have any entries.

Comment: as i understood First question`s answer: I cant because i can find five matrices which are cannot be linear combination of one another. for example ... and i will find example :) is it acceptable ?

Comment: @Andy: The two parts of the first question have different answers. In one case you can always write one of the five matrices as a linear combination of the others, so you need a proof of this, not an example. In the other case it is possible to find five matrices such that none of them is a linear combination of the others, and you need to find an example like that. HINT: What is the dimension of the space of $3\times 3$ matrices?

Comment: then how about this answer ? : 
_i can express 2x2 five matrix as one 4x5 matrix such that by the row reduction operation i can say(prove) that the 5th column(matrix) is linear combination of other matrices._

Answer (score 2):

The **dimension** of the vector space $V$ is the **cardinality** of a **basis** in this vector space and it's also the **maximal** number of **linearly independant** vectors of $V$ (*or the minimal number of vectors which  span $V$*). Now what's the dimension of $\mathcal{M}_2(\Bbb R)$? of $\mathcal{M}_3(\Bbb R)$?  Can you take it from here?

For your second question, what's the sum of Four vectors in   that form a loop when end-to-end connected? What's this mean using the notion of *linearly independant*?

Comment: Another well-deserved $\uparrow$!